# Boot Camp Assistant Missing?

Tags: macos, bootcamp

I was trying to modify boot camp assistant info.plist in order to boot from usb and then it suddenly disappeared. 
Macbook A1342 Unibody 
10.8.5

If any one at least share boot camp assistant app with me. I do not have start up dvd to reinstall.

Comment: Normally we close questions asking for downloading parts of the system, however if there is an excellent workaround lets see if you can rescue things without needing a backup of your system. Anyone seeing a link to software, use proper caution installing things from the Internet.

Comment: @bmike Never mind, the Recovery HD doesn't contain the Boot Camp Assistant like I thought it had :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Recovery partition to reinstall OS X. This will keep your user account but reset all system files.

To reinstall OS X, boot with ⌘R and select the **Reinstall OS X** option, then follow the instructions.

Additionally, this file is normally backed up to the local time machine store, so try entering Time Machine even if you don't have your drive connected to see about restoring that file.

Worst case, have some trusted people MD5 check sum the app on 10.8.5 if you want to risk downloading it from a stranger instead of from a friend's backup or Mac.

Comment: Downloading OsX, we'll see the result in a few hours.